# WPF/c#: How to solve thread problem while using SplashScreen / Loading Screen

Tags: c#, wpf

Due to some of my page windows will loading big amount of calculation before it shown, hence I created a WPF Window and make it to be a Loading Screen with GIF to show before the page rendered.

When I want the loading screen come out , I use this code :

> Loading.ShowSplashScreen();

After the page loaded, I will use the code below to close the loading screen

> Loading.CloseForm();

And the code behind of loading page are in the following:

```
public partial class Loading : Window
{
    private static Loading LD;
    public static Dictionary<string, object> Dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public Loading()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static public void ShowSplashScreen()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Loading sw = new Loading();
            Dic["Loading"] = sw;
                sw.ShowDialog();
            });
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
    }

    static public void CloseForm()
    {
        if (Loading.Dic.ContainsKey("Loading"))
        {
            Loading sw = Loading.Dic["Loading"] as Loading;
            sw.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => sw.Close()));
        }
    }
}
```

It's no problem when I "First Times" call out the loading screen, but I will having an error once I "Second Times" call out the loading screen and the error in the following :

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

May anyone can help me to see how to solve this problem ?
Many Thanks !

Comment: There is no need for some extra splash thread - have a look at https://github.com/SirRufo/WpfWithSplash

Comment: The code has a threading race bug, nothing great happens when you call ShowSplashScreen() a second time before CloseForm() runs.  The dictionary entry gets overwritten before it is used.  Partition the code correctly, keep UI on the main thread and background work on a worker thread.

Comment: @Sir Rufo I'm not use this only for the first loading on App opening, I need to use custom splash sheet on most of the page which need to load a lot of calculation....

Comment: @Hans Passant I'm not really understand due to I'm new in WPF & c#, may tell me more clearly how can I solve the problem or how to make it on worker thread ?

Comment: It does not matter where and when you need a splash - you never need another thread for the splash. Instead run the calculation in another thread context

Comment: @Sir Rufo Did your mean all the UI in my app should be in main thread which included splashscreen, then run all/selected calculation in another new thread ?

Comment: Yes, of course. BTW the main thread is often also called the UI thread, guess why ;o)

Comment: @Sir Rufo I see, I thinking how to make it because I was developed all the page already =.=... So if let say I have to make all the page to a seperated thread because of a loading page... that is....